# Including more than one js file in cache.manifest?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, manifest, offline-caching

I am working with sencha touch 2 in MVC format. I have created a cache.manifest file to bring my app offline.

```
CACHE MANIFEST

index.html
app.js
guide.css
app/model/Contact.js
app/model/Injury.js
app/view/IncidentForm.js
app/view/Home.js
app/view/DivisionSelect.js
app/view/InjuryResponse.js
app/view/EmergencyContact.js
app/controller/Core.js
i/amcor-app-bg@2.png
i/amcor-bg-logo@2.png
i/amcor-logo.png
i/amcor-tb-logo2x.png
i/arrow_right.png
i/ec-icon@2.png
i/home_icon.png
i/in-icon@2.png
i/ir-icon2x.png
i/ir-icon@2.png
i/ir-toolbar-bg2x.png



st2/builds/sencha-touch-all-compat.js
st2/resources/css/sencha-touch.css

NETWORK:
*
```

My issue is that the cache.manifest file does not seem to recognize any of my js files except for app.js. When I am working online it seems to cache properly but when I go offline the cache only returns index.html, app.js, and the sencha files. Can the cache.manifest file only have one .js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really try to use the [tools SDK](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/download) then you don't have to worry at all.

The Microloader helps keep things up to date.

Its a bit light on its error checking output and you must conform to the MVC app layout created by the SDK tools but once its running "it just works".

If the "compile" hangs its probably a missing ref.